# Finding a way to preg_match all special letters

Tags: php, preg-match

Basically I was trying to preg_match all Letters and special letters for example: ä,â,ã… But I‘ve come across to a problem. Preg_Matching only letters was pretty easy since you only need the following code: `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/")` the hard part was when adding all special letters. I‘ve come across some methods like `preg_match("/^[äöü ÄÖÜ a-z-]+$/")` to manually preg_match some special letters but isn’t there something like a syntax that can preg_match all of the special letter?

Comment: Maybe `[^\s\w]+` with `u` modifier? Can you define `special letters` or give more examples?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "special character". All characters are equal, they are characters. Nothing "special" on some of them, no magic here.

Answer (score 1):

I think I’ve found an answer for my question with the following code:

```
preg_match('/[^\pL\s-]/u', $string)
```

This should work since it should accept all special letters but I‘ve not tested it.

Comment: Hard to say if that "should accept all special letters" without you actually specifying what characters you refer to by that.